# Create bar chart in Matplotlib where a column has no name

Tags: python

I'm trying to create a bar chart using matplotlib using two columns but one of the has no name which I think is causing my problem. The data looks like this -

| SALE_DATE |  |
| --- | --- |
| 2010 | 20984 |
| 2011 | 18421 |
| 2012 | 25349 |
| 2013 | 30191 |
| 2014 | 43611 |

The right hand column has no name. I was hoping to use something like this -

```
by_year.plot.bar(x='SALE_DATE', y='TOTAL')
```

Do I need to name the right column and if so how do i do it?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When posting questions, it is usually helpful to provide a working example, ie code or csv to generate your data.

```
dat = [
       [2010, 20984],
       [2011, 18421],
       [2012, 25349], 
       [2013, 30191],
       [2014, 43611]
     ]
cols = ['Year', 'Total']
df = pd.DataFrame(dat, columns=cols)

df
```

Out

```
   Year  Total
0  2010  20984
1  2011  18421
2  2012  25349
3  2013  30191
4  2014  43611
```

pandas `plot` method uses matplotlib under the hood, and returns a matplotlib `Axes` object.
You can modify the ylabel on the output Axes object: [set_ylabel](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_ylabel.html)

```
ax = df.plot.bar(x='Year', y='Total')
ax.set_ylabel('Total')
```

[image: Output plot]

Comment: Thank you so much, still a noob to this and seeing the answer broken down so neatly really helps!